# Node dbus Network Manager IPV6 addresses property binding

Tags: node.js, ipv6, dbus, networkmanager

I am having issues with the "addresses" as well as the "address-data" properties in Network Manager Dbus API for ipv6 connection.  For addresses, it is stated they are looking for an array of structs of ipv6 objects which would be Array of (Array of BYTE, UINT32, Array of BYTE) sig - a(ayuay)  The link to the Gnome documentation is here https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/1.10/settings-ipv6.html

```
'address-data': [ {'address': settings.ip, 'prefix':settings.subnet} ],
'gateway': settings.gateway,
```

after some experimenting I am receiving errors that are actually JS stack dumps instead of daemon errors.  Has anyone had any luck getting this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone running into this issue, I finally got it to work correctly.  Using nodejs [dbus-native](https://github.com/sidorares/dbus-native) library.  Here is the correct way to form the ipv6 property for use with dbus and Network Manager

```
['802-3-ethernet',
    [
      ['auto-negotiate', ['b', 1]],
    ]
  ],
  ['connection',
    [
      ['id', ['s', 'some name']],
      ['type', ['s','802-3-ethernet']],
      ['uuid', ['s', uuidv4()]],
      ['interface-name', ['s', 'name of interface (eth0, wlan0)']],
      ['autoconnect', ['b', 1]]
    ]
  ],
  ['ipv4',
    [
      ['method', ['s','auto']]
    ]
  ],
  ['ipv6',
    [
      ['method', ['s','manual']],
      ['ip6-privacy', ['i', -1]]
      ['dns',
        ['aay',
          [
            [
              '2001:4860:4860::8888',  //needs to be array or buffer of uint8
              '2001:4860:4860::8844'  //needs to be array or buffer of uint8
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ],
      ['addresses',
        ['a(ayuay)',
          [
            [
              [
                'static ipv6 ip',  //needs to be array or buffer of uint8
                parseInt(CIDR, example: 64),
                'ipv6 gateway ip'  //needs to be array or buffer of uint8
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```